# jQuery get all non checked checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox color" name="color[]" value="Gray">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox color" name="color[]" value="red">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox color" name="color[]" value="black">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox color" name="color[]" value="yellow">
```

jQuery:

```
$(".color").click(function(){
    console.log($(".color:not(:checked)").val());
})
```

My code is working but it displaying only one element. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: `$('.color...`. Dot is important.

Comment: Just remove the `.val()` so you can see the array returned in the console. Here is a [JSfiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/qxhksusL/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use following script for this, [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1oocqfnc/)

```js
$(".color").change(function(){
 $(".color").each(function(){
  if (!$(this).prop("checked")) {
   alert($(this).val());
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox color" name="color[]" value="Gray">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox color" name="color[]" value="red">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox color" name="color[]" value="black">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox color" name="color[]" value="yellow">
```

Comment: Are you sure this is what OP wants?

Comment: I'm not saying this _won't work_. The title of question is _jQuery get all non checked checkbox_. You don't understand the question. I request you to read it again.

Comment: @Tushar, first you can check answer,

Comment: To be fair to @Tushar the OP has changed the question.

Comment: Yeah. For the current question, this will work. _Not my downvote_.

Comment: @Tushar Ya i agree with you, but we are giving good solution also

Comment: You could do this using `map()` as well, see [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/608f4t8s/).

Answer (score 0):

[@super-user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3756181/super-user) has provided a perfectly acceptable [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43657283/692942) but you could streamline this further by using the jQuery [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) function to translate the array and then use `join()` to output the result as a string.

```js
$(".color").click(function(){ 
  $("p").text(jQuery.map($(".color:not(:checked)"), function(val, index) {
    return $(val).val();
  }).join(",")); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox color" name="color[]" value="Gray">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox color" name="color[]" value="red">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox color" name="color[]" value="black">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox color" name="color[]" value="yellow">
<p></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("input[name='color[]']").each( function () {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) 
  {                                 
  }
  else
  {
  }
});
```